# Send e-mail when a Puppet service stops

Tags: linux, email, puppet

In the company where I work, we have Puppet running in some servers to ensure that all the computers are well configured.

But we had some trouble where some people were deactivating Puppet without notifying the responsible team.

While we limit their access, we thought about a  “trigger” that sends an e-mail when Puppet service is stopped by an user.

I did some research and found a lot of commands for that: `at` and `audit`.

Audit seems the best option for this situation. Have you guys done this? Are there any other tool I can use in this situation?

Comment: I would highly recommend using [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/). It is easy to use and very flexible. It can email when a service has triggered an alert and can even attempt to restart a service as well. [More details here](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples) and you can even configure your own Monit rules for custom apps.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would have puppet sending reports somewhere that would keep track of each puppet run for the last few days and would also alert if it hasn't received a report in X number of hours/minutes.  [Foreman](https://theforeman.org/) or [Puppet Dashboard](https://github.com/sodabrew/puppet-dashboard) can do that.  There are others.

Comes in handy when you want to see what changes have occurred to a server.

Absent that, if you're just looking for a poor man's service monitor something like this in cron running once an hour will give you plenty of spam (assuming systemd init system).

```
systemctl --quiet is-active puppet.service  || (systemctl status puppet.service | mail -S "Puppet stopped on $HOSTNAME" sysadmins@example.com)
```

Or put monit on as [Giacomo1968](https://superuser.com/questions/1417776/send-e-mail-when-a-puppet-service-stops/1418451#comment2140539_1417776) suggested.